# What does Night Terror of Darwin Village do?

Tags: wasteland-2

I cannot interact with it at all after I opened the cage, neither talk nor use other skills. Wiki says it will follow you after released it. But all I can see is that it's standing there and do nothing.

Is it a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you left the building if so is it following? Once it's open it'll follow if you feed it body parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked to him, but did not have any "candy" at the time.  He still followed me.

The "candy" he asks for is any meat (human, animal, etc., including items like Gila Skins).  You can talk to him any time after he's released, and open a trade interface to give him "candy".

If you give him enough, eventually he announces that he's sleepy, and he will stop following you.

I do not know if he comes back at any point after that.

He does not participate in any combat, but has about 8000 points of health, so he's incredibly durable.

Comment: I assume that's a bug since no matter how hard I try, it just don't give a fck about me...

Answer (score 2):

talk to it to give it "Meat candy" and when it goes to sleep hit it for about 1/3 of its health bar in damage, and it will explode, for a decent chunk of XP, like 3600? you got a whopping 36000 for killing them in wastelands 1, and make sure you feed it and it goes to sleep first, or you'll end up getting like 30xp and waste your ammo, it's 20 pieces of meat to make it fall asleep, if you attack it while it's awake it hits for like 8 damage melee, it's just a joke from wasteland 1 that they put it in the game so weakly, considering the originals were no joke. also once it goes to sleep if you leave the area, you'll never see it again, ever.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you need to feed "candy" to him first. And by "candy" he means "meat". After that he follows you around. I don't remember if he actually engages in combat, I think he doesn't. So he just follows you around. Since he's very tough (at least he was in the beta) you won't get rid of him easily.

Comment: How do I feed it? I have some human flesh (eye, hand, heart... etc) but they're unusable. And there's no option on The Night Terror, I cant interact with it.